# javascript to load the html code

Tags: javascript, html

```css
body {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #808080;
}
p {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #808080;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
hr {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #808080;
}

a:link {
  color: #B2AB19;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: inherent;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B2AB19;
}
a:active {
  color: inherent;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: #B2AB19;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
#container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #EF9898;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#lcolumn {
  float: left;
  max-width: 250px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#rcolumn {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 250px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function getheaderHTML() {
    var content =  '  <div id="nav">'
    +'    <a href="index.html">number 1</a>｜<a href="students.html">number 2</a>'
    +'  </div>'
    +'  <div id="header">'
    +'    <img src="header.jpg" alt="testing" width=100% height=260>'
    +'  </div>';
    document.body.innerHTML = content;
  }
  function getfooterHTML() {
    var content =  '  <div id="footer">'
    +'    &#169;2016'
    +'  </div>'
    document.body.innerHTML = content;
  }
</script>

<div id="container">
  <script>
    getheaderHTML();
  </script>
  <div id="lcolumn">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div id="rcolumn">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    getfooterHTML();
  </script>
</div>
```

I would like to use javascript to avoid repetitive code of formatting the layout of multiple webpages, so that when I change the layout, I will only need to change the content of one file. I was told that document.write is not a good idea to do this and a member was kind enough to suggest the above javascript code. However, it does not load the desired result. Could you please advise? Thank you so much.

Comment: And why do we need all this css?

Comment: the div settings are in the css

Comment: And what? Is your problem connected with css?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `document.write()` here. It has it's valid uses as long as you have control over the content string.

Comment: when i tried the code, the content of the header can be loaded, but not the css setting of the header.

Comment: now when i run the code here, the footer completely disappears.

Comment: Thank you Spencer for your encouragement. My previous javascript was function getheaderHTML() {
 document.write('  <div id="nav">');
 document.write('    <a href="index.html">number 1</a>｜<a href="students.html">number 2</a>');
 document.write('  </div>');
 document.write('  <div id="header">');
 document.write('    <img src="header.jpg" alt="testing" width=100% height=260>');
 document.write('  </div>');
}
function getfooterHTML() {
 document.write('  <div id="footer">');
 document.write('    &#169;2016');
 document.write('  </div>');
}

Comment: The code suggestion will not work how you expect it to. When you do `document.body.innerHTML = ...` you are clearing and replacing all the HTML inside the `body` tag during the call.

Comment: Thank you Spencer. Do you think I should keep document.write in this case or really should refactor the code as suggested? If you think it's no harm to do the latter, could you please help correct?

Comment: @Sen Just note thing about `document.write` is it needs to be called inside the areas you wish to write. Calling it anytime after the DOM loads will clear it, so you need to be careful.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. The way I use to judge is whether the desired result can be loaded.

Comment: @Sen I think using `document.write()` would be fine here. Although you could also have blank tags `<div id="nav"></div>` and `<div id="footer"></div>` and have your functions change the `.innerHTML` of those elements.

Comment: Thank you Spencer. It's so kind of you.

Comment: I am browsing your web :P

Comment: @Sen add a `+`  infront of `=`  like. `document.body.innerHTML = content` also I didn't know you were new to JavaScript hence In your previous question I just suggested better approach than what you had . But from the looks of it.. The task you are after can be done much better and easily using Jquery. I like your kindness. I will give a detailed page with loading contents dynamically according to pages. I'll get back to you in 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you so much Rajshekar Reddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recomend you to use some template engine like [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html).
With pug you can easily re-use code and make your code more readable and organized.
Hope my advice works.

Comment: Thank you Esteban. I was not aware of such useful resource before.

Comment: I would suggest [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) rather then Pug. It's really simple and very powerful template system

Comment: pretty much the same thing no? i mean, i do not use Mustache but it seems pretty much the same.